# Scala ZIO Stream -- Convert Stream[A] to Stream[B] where one A produces zero or more B

Tags: scala, zio, scalaz-stream

I have a `Stream[A]` and a function `zeroOrMoreB(value: A): Seq[B]` which given an `A` returns zero or more `B`. From these two pieces, how to I construct a `Stream[B]`?

I can get a `Stream[Stream[B]]` (see below), but I cannot figure out how to flatten it.

```
stream <- ZStream
  .fromIterable(vectorOfAs)
  .map(zeroOrMoreB)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://javadoc.io/doc/dev.zio/zio-streams_2.13/latest/zio/stream/ZStream.html) is your friend.

You can use `mapConcat`

```
val stream = ZStream.fromIterable(vectorOfAs).mapConcat(zeroOrMoreB)
```

Now if `zeroOrMoreB` actually returns a **ZStream** instead of a **Seq**, you just use `flatMap`

```
val stream = ZStream.fromIterable(vectorOfAs).flatMap(zeroOrMoreB)
```

Finally, if you like **for** syntax you can do this

```
val stream = for {
  a <- ZStream.fromIterable(vectorOfAs)
  b <- ZStream.fromIterable(zeroOrMoreB(a))
} yield b
```

Answer (score 0):

I was clearly not thinking straight -- `.flatMap` does the trick.

```
stream <- ZStream
  .fromIterable(vectorOfAs)
  .flatMap(a => zeroOrMoreB(a))
```